# excel vba - copy unique values to new sheet - NO HEADER

Tags: excel, vba

I have column A in the srcSheet with the following 10 values:

```
bob
mary
sez
mary
mik
bob
tim
bob
ni
whit
```

I'm trying to copy the unique values only to column A in another sheet but I'm getting the first value 'bob' twice. I know this is because AdvancedFilter treats first row as a header but I want to know if this can be done in VBA without putting in a header row above?

my code:

```
Set rSrc = Worksheets(srcSheet).Range("A1:10")
Set rTrg = Worksheets(trgSheet).Range("A1")

rSrc.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rTrg, Unique:=True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option to not include the header.  You could delete the top item after the copy

```
With rTrg.offset(1,0)
   Range(.Item(1), .End(xlDown)).Cut rTrg
End With
```

...or something similar which works with your particular sheet layout.

EDIT: much tidier to just do something like this

```
Sub Tester()
    CopyUniques Sheet1.Range("C4").CurrentRegion, Sheet1.Range("e4")
End Sub


Sub CopyUniques(rngCopyFrom As Range, rngCopyTo As Range)
    Dim d As Object, c As Range, k
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rngCopyFrom
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            If Not d.Exists(c.Value) Then d.Add c.Value, 1
        End If
    Next c
    k = d.keys
    rngCopyTo.Resize(UBound(k) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(k)
End Sub
```

Comment: what if the first value weren't duplicated?

Comment: Test for count > 1 first: `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rTrg, rTrg.Cells(1, 1)) > 1 Then`